What is it called when a group generates prose by voting on each new character?
Claude Shannon's "Prediction and Entropy of Printed English" describes a group of people  predicting the next character of prose given the text leading up to that character. The more predictable a character, the less information it conveys.  The less predictable, the more information it conveys.
What is the experiment called where group of people predicts the next character, given a prior "prompt", to generate rather than predict prose?

Chain writing
